# $u,v$ harmonic conjugates where $f=u+iv$, is $g=v-iu$ analytic in D

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

So I think the proof is straight forward, but looking for verifications:

$$g(z)=v-iu=-i[iv-i^2u]=-i[iv-(-1)u]=-i[u+iv]=-if(z)$$

So $g$ is a multiple of $f$ and thus $g$ would satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations as $f$ did, and so $g$ is also analytic.

Is this enough?

Comment: OK. Simple proof.

Comment: I suspect the point of the problem was practice in applying the CR conditions. But noting that $g$ is a multiple of $f$ and therefore satisfies CR by a known result indicates a good eye on your part.

Comment: Thank you!  Saw how the terms were rotated and kinda intuited from there.